# Get values of all inputs inside a form with flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have this `jinja2` code :

```
<div class="form-group input-group col-xs-6 col-md-5">

                    {% for param in params %}

                        <input type="text" name="listParam" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ param.name|e }}[{{param.type[0]|e}}]" required>
                    {% endfor %}



</div>
```

and I would like to get the values of all inputs inside this form.
I tried this code :

```
@app.route('/testmessage', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def testmessage():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    a=request.form.get('listParam')
    return a
 return ''
```

But I get only the value of the first input.
So how can I get the values of all inputs ?

Comment: my guess is because they all share the same name listParam. I'm not sure how that functions in browsers, maybe the last element in the page with the given name is the one who can be accessed by it. Is the value of a returned that of the last element? Give each text a distinct value and see which is returned.

Comment: @idjaw
`request.form` returns the following error: `TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable`

Comment: @jxramos
yes, I think that the problem is that they share all the same name. but how can I give them diferent name since the number of inputs depends on the variable `params` ?

Comment: I'm not sure the most elegant way, but you're in python so you could increment a counter variable and append it to the end of the names to yield listParam0, listParam1, etc. But look into the documentation or something and see if there's a way to load children objects. print the type of the form too with print(type(request.form)), that should give you something to search documentation against.